# why does catchError get called a million times in my spec?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have code that does something like:

```
  makeApiCall() {
    this.client.call().pipe(
      first(),
      catchError((error, caught) => {
        console.log('error!!!');
        this.error = true;
        return caught;
      })
    ).subscribe((response: Response) => { stuff... });
  }
```

And then my test does:

```
  let response: Subject<Response>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    response = new Subject();
    const client = jasmine.createSpyObj('Client', ['call']);
    (client.call as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(response);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ....
      providers: [
        { provide: Client, useValue: client },
      ... etc.
    });

    describe('an error', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        component.makeApiCall();
        response.error({ status: 422 });
      });

      it('sets the error flag', () => {
        expect(component.error).toEqual(true);
      });
    });
  });
```

I run this, and the test passes but it console logs 'error!!!' a billion times..  Why is it executing this catchError so many times???

Answer (score 0):

you've wrapped your "an error" test inside `beforeEach` which means this code will run *on every test you have elsewhere*.  I assume you have more tests than you are showing in this example.  But you'll get that print statement for every single one of them

Comment: That before each is only for that describe block, and there is only one test in that block.  That one test console logs a billion times.

Comment: you should add a complete repro to your Q.  You've only provided snippets which aren't enough to help identify the issue

Comment: the answer is `return caught` makes it catch the error a billion times. return EMPTY makes it not do that.